# type of tally-marks and want to remove verticle line from table

Tags: tables

Question: 1 Go through following mwe, I want fifth line like \ instead of /.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}

\newcount\tallycount
\newcommand{\dotally}{%
\loop\ifnum\tallycount>4\relax\StrokeFive\
\advance\tallycount by-5\repeat
\ifcase\tallycount\or\StrokeOne\or\StrokeTwo\or
\StrokeThree\or\Strokefour\else ERROR\fi\unskip}

\newcommand{\tally}{\afterassignment\dotally\tallycount }

\begin{document}
\tally 10

\end{document}
```

Question: 2 How can i use the tally marks in second column of my table given below. Further i don't want a line in the fifth raw of table after the word total.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.8 in,bottom=0.8 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.7ex} \textbf{x} & \textbf{Tally Marks} & \textbf{y}\\ 
    \hline \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.7ex} A &  & $8$\\ 
    \hline \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.7ex} B &  & $14$\\ 
    \hline \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.7ex} AB &  & $13$\\ 
    \hline \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.7ex} O &  & $10$\\ 
    \hline \rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.7ex} \textbf{Total} &  & $\boldsymbol{45}$\\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
You have error in definition of macro `\tally`. Instead `\Strokefour` you should use `\StrokeFour`!

Beside this you have controversy in page size definition. Is it "letter" size or "A4"? In the following example I consider A4 as you put in `geometry` options (which I simplified to equal margin an all page's sides).

Regarding table, see if the following example is what you looking for:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper,margin=1 in]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcount\tallycount
\newcommand{\dotally}{%
    \loop\ifnum\tallycount>4\relax\StrokeFive\  
         \advance\tallycount by-5%
    \repeat%
    \ifcase \tallycount\or\StrokeOne\or\StrokeTwo\or\StrokeThree\or\StrokeFour
    \else   ERROR
    \fi%
    \unskip}
\newcommand{\tally}{\afterassignment\dotally\tallycount }

    \begin{document}   
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
\textbf{x}      & \textbf{Tally Marks}
                                & \textbf{y}    \\  \hline
A               &   \tally 8    & $8$           \\  \hline
B               &   \tally 14   & $14$          \\  \hline
AB              &   \tally 13   & $13$          \\  \hline
O               &   \tally 10   & $10$          \\  \hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Total}}
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{45}}
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

However, to my opinion, the table will look more nice, if you will omit vertical lines and for horizontal use rules from `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper,margin=1 in]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

    \usepackage{booktabs}

\newcount\tallycount
\newcommand{\dotally}{%
    \loop\ifnum\tallycount>4\relax\StrokeFive\  
         \advance\tallycount by-5%
    \repeat%
    \ifcase \tallycount\or\StrokeOne\or\StrokeTwo\or\StrokeThree%\or\StrokeFour
    \else   ERROR
    \fi%
    \unskip}
\newcommand{\tally}{\afterassignment\dotally\tallycount }

    \begin{document}   
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \toprule
\textbf{x}      & \textbf{Tally Marks}
                                & \textbf{y}    \\  
    \midrule
A               &   \tally 8    & $8$           \\
B               &   \tally 14   & $14$          \\
AB              &   \tally 13   & $13$          \\
O               &   \tally 15   & $15$          \\
    \bottomrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Total}}
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{50}}
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Here I change row "O" from 10 to 15 to show three stroked groups.  Compilation is performed without of errors and gives the following result:

[image]

Comment: i tried a lot to compile but it didn't. And you are right codes not working for 4, 14, 24, etc. so what is next? please help me. my questions were very simple. i explain it, My first question was in the mwe when you see 5th tally marks appear over previous four in / manner. but i want 5th one as \ instead of /. and second question is i am looking forward to add tally marks in table according the values given in y column.

Comment: @snehal, after Herbert correction my spelling errors in mine answer, I figured out the error in macro `tally`. It is typing error (see my revised answer) . Now both mine MWE works without any problem (I use recent 64-bit MikTeX, if this matter).